# php print function doesnt return anything

Tags: php, mysql

i'm new to php and i'm having trouble running this code as when i run it, the browser shows nothing. just blank. can anyone help me with it, determine what the problem is. btw, i am running a wamp server ver. 2.2 hence the mysql tags. this code is for a search function for a database i created, also the edit section of the function does the same. it shows nothing on the browser.

EDIT: fixed the code. although there's this weird output on the table that shows another completely blank.
WHAT I DID: used isset() and there we're variables that needs tweaking examples we're the $rows which i wrote $row.

```
<html>
    <title>Search Records</title>
    <body>
        <center>
            <?php require 'connect.php' ?>

                <?php
                    //===SEARCH RECORDS===//
                    if(isset($_GET['search'])=='Search Records')
                        {
                            print "<br>Search Records";
                            print
                                "<center>
                                <form method=POST action >
                                <input type= text size=30 name=mysearch><br>
                                <input type=submit name=search1 value='Search'>
                                </center>
                                </form>";
                        }
                    if(isset($_GET['search1'])=='Search')
                        {
                            $result=mysql_query
                            (
                                "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE
                                ID  LIKE  '%$_GET[mysearch]%' or 
                                fname LIKE  '%$_GET[mysearch]%' or 
                                mname LIKE  '%$_GET[mysearch]%' or 
                                lname LIKE  '%$_GET[mysearch]%' or 
                                age LIKE  '%$_GET[mysearch]%' or
                                gender LIKE  '%$_GET[mysearch]%' or 
                                dob LIKE  '%$_GET[mysearch]%'or 
                                ssn LIKE  '%$_GET[mysearch]%' or 
                                salary LIKE  '%$_GET[mysearch]%' 
                                order by lname asc"
                            ) or die (mysql_error());

                            if($_GET['mysearch']==null)
                                {
                                    print mysql_error();
                                }
                                else
                                    $rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

                            if(isset($rows)!=0)
                                {
                                    echo "<br>Search Results";
                                    echo "<table border=1 align=center cellspacing=0>";
                                    echo
                                    "<tr align=center>
                                    <td>ID Number</td>
                                    <td>First Name</td>
                                    <td>Middle Name</td>
                                    <td>Last Name</td>
                                    <td>Age</td>
                                    <td>Gender</td>
                                    <td>Date of Birth</td>
                                    <td>Salary</td>
                                    <td>SSN</td>
                                    <td>Action</td>  
                                    </tr>";

                                    for($i=0; $i< $rows; $i++)
                                        {
                                            $rows=mysql_fetch_row($result);
                                            echo "<tr align=center>";
                                            echo "<td>$rows[0]</td>";           
                                            echo "<td>$rows[1]</td>";                          
                                            echo "<td>$rows[2]</td>";
                                            echo "<td>$rows[3]</td>";
                                            echo "<td>$rows[4]</td>";
                                            echo "<td>$rows[5]</td>";
                                            echo "<td>$rows[6]</td>";
                                            echo "<td>$rows[7]</td>";
                                            echo "<td>$rows[8]</td>";
                                            echo "<td>[<a href=deleterecords.php?action=Delete&id=$rows[0]>Delete</a>]
                                                [<a href=FreeElec1.php?action=Edit&id=$rows[0]>Edit</a>]</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        }
                                    echo "</table>";
                                    echo "<font size=1>Number of entries found: $rows</font>";
                                    echo "<br><br><input type=button value=Back onClick=history.go(-1);return true;>";
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    echo "<br>No records found!";
                                    echo "<br><input type=button value=Back onClick=history.go(-1);return true;>";
                                }
                            mysql_free_result($result);
                        }
                    mysql_error();
                    mysql_close($link);
                ?>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't use a snippet with php only html, css, javascript

Comment: @SuperDJ my apologies. i am new to programming and new to the site too. will remember that next time.

Comment: where is connection with database?

Comment: `if (@$_GET['action'] == "Search Record")` your print rely on the condtion, i posted one is my comment. they should be met before it print some thing. hope it help a little

Comment: @user3172176 the connection php is added.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 there is an html button in relation to this code. when i press that button, nothing happens. the print does not return anything to the browser.

Comment: jesseree i know thats why you are using the $_GET print work fine, your conditions are not fine hope you understand what i tried to say in the last comment. Thanks

Comment: and one more thing post the link or button or form which every you are using to get the value for $_get, means add that things in you question you are likely to get positive response. Now at the moment we know your condition is failing, but why its failing dont know fully, know some mistakes but dont have complete picture. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, test the query in phpMyAdmin to see if the query returns anything.

Second of all: avoid using @ in php. Use this instead:

```
if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'blah')
```

Last of all, use the following to see what each variable contains. Like this you can debug easier:

```
var_dump($_GET['action']);


var_dump($result);


var_dump($row);
```

Comment: If you want to retrieve a $_GET['action'] variable use http://yoururl?action=search

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with your Print code.

there is no connection to database.if you made it somewhere, then check it
use var_dump(); or firebug in your browser to see what its getting and what its posting.

Comment: i've added the php for the connection to the database. what exactly am i looking for in using var_dump() note: i'm not sure how to use var_dump and how to interpret the things it displays on the browser